# "Truncate" String Column in another column?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a table with a column containing String values. The String values always end with a letter "T" as the last character, a space " " and a number is right after the string:

```
StringColumn
"asdjadhasdT 32 asjashudT 2"
"tytweytwe aweriuhfT 23"
"ajkjsdT 6 asdajkdjkjT 1445"
"kjkasd aaassT 980"
```

I would like to get the number in another column.

In other words:

```
StringColumn                        |    ColumnValues
"asdjadhasdT 32 asjashudT 2"        |    2
"tytweytwe aweriuhfT 23"            |    23
"ajkjsdT 6 asdajkdjkjT 1445"        |    1445
"kjkasd aaassT 980"                 |    980
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you also have a space after the `'T'`.  Here is one approach:

```
select StringColumn, substr(StringColumn, 2 - instr(reverse(StringColumn), 'T')) as Values
from . . .
```

This finds the position of `'T'` in the reversed string, and then takes that many characters minus two from the end of the string.

EDIT:

```
with t as (
     select 'asdjadhasdT 32 asjashudT 2' as StringColumn from dual union all
     select 'tytweytwe aweriuhfT 23' as StringColumn from dual union all
     select 'ajkjsdT 6 asdajkdjkjT 1445' as StringColumn from dual union all
     select 'kjkasd aaassT 980' as StringColumn from dual
)
select StringColumn,
       substr(StringColumn, 2-instr(reverse(StringColumn), 'T')) as "Values"
from t;
```

SQL Fiddle is [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/14384).

The problem with the first version is that `Values` is a reserved word in Oracle, so the query fails to compile.

Comment: yes, I always have a space between the number and a letter "T". I am going to check this solution. Thank you

Comment: I am sorry but is not working properly.... I have more exceptions in the table... I'm editing it right now. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

i took the input strings provided and 
got the position of last occurence of 'T' and then took a substring below is the Query :

**SELECT StringColumn,Trim(SubStr(StringColumn,INSTR(StringColumn,'T',-1 )+1)) FROM test;**

Thanks,
Koustubh Avadhani